# How to exclude IE < 11 in autoprefixer config?

Tags: autoprefixer

I want autoprefixer to add prefixes for `last 2 versions`, but it includes IE10.
Settings like `browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'not ie < 11']` still includes IE10.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of browserlist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries) says, that your config is right. You can also try it here: [browserl.ist](http://browserl.ist/?q=last%202%20versions%2C%20not%20ie%20%3C%2011)

So I guess your problem is somewhere else. How do you see that it includes IE10?

Comment: Your syntax is correct. Last 2 versions are the last 2 released versions so that would include Edge, IE11. Not ie < 11 is also correct syntax. Possibly webpack is not using your rules due to an error elsewhere.